# How do you keep text from wrapping in an NSTableView using NSAttributedString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an NSTableView that has 2 columns, one for an icon and the other for two lines of text. In the second column, the text column, I have some larger text that is for the name of an item. Then I have a new line and some smaller text that describes the state of the item.

When the name becomes so large that it doesn't fit on one line it wraps (or when you shrink the window down so small that it causes the names to not fit on a single line).

row1===============
| image |  some name   |
| image |   idle               |
row2================
| image |  some name really long name   | <- this gets wrapped pushing 'idle' out of the view
| image |   idle               |
===================

My question is, how could I keep the text from wrapping and just have the NSTableView display a horizontal scroll-bar once the name is too large to fit?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Scrolling in Cocoa is implemented with the `NSScrollView` which is a *view* instead of a *cell* so if you really want to implement horizontal scrolling for table view cells I think you'd have to subclass the whole `NSTableView` and implement the feature there. My suggestion (without knowing the specifics of your situation, of course) is that you don't do that, though, since it's **nonstandard behaviour** and would probably entail quite a bit of work.

#### Truncate Instead of Wrap

If you're using a standard `NSTextFieldCell`, just select "Truncates" for its *layout* value in IB instead of "Wraps".

If you have a custom `NSCell` where you're doing your own drawing (I assume this is the case here), you should create an `NSParagraphStyle`, set its line break mode, add it as a value for the `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName` key in the `NSAttributedString`'s text attributes dictionary.

An example:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init] autorelease];
[paragraphStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
[attributedStr
 addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
 value:paragraphStyle
 range:NSMakeRange(0,[attributedStr length])];
```

#### Cell Expansion Frames

If you don't want to wrap your lines of text in the table view cells, the standard method of allowing the user to see the whole text is to use **cell expansion frames** which are enabled by default:

> Cell expansion can occur when the mouse hovers over the specified cell and the cell contents are unable to be fully displayed within the cell.

If they're not working for some reason and you're using a custom `NSCell` subclass, make sure you implement `-drawWithExpansionFrame:inView:` and `-expansionFrameWithFrame:inView:` in your cell. Also make sure you're not returning `NO` in your `NSTableViewDelegate` for `-tableView:shouldShowCellExpansionForTableColumn:row:` (if you have one).

#### Adjust Width of Whole Table View?

If what you want to do is to adjust the width of a specific column (and thus the whole table view, possibly causing the enclosing scroll view's horizontal scroll bar to appear) such that the text its cells contain would never be truncated or wrapped, you can probably do that in your `NSTableViewDelegate`, for example, by calling `-cellSize` for each row's cell in that column and resizing the column to the largest value (you'll want to only do this when the values change, of course).

Comment: TY for a great, and detailed, response :)

Comment: Amazing response on a niche topic; the paragraphStyle approach solved an issue I was having where long NSAttributedStrings didn't truncate in an NSTableView cell, resulting in some text being not properly centered horizontally due to wrapping instead of truncation. Thank you!